# Preparing to use BTRFS in Debian 7 Wheezy

Tags: debian, btrfs

### Kernel

According to the [BTRFS wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Getting_started) support is green-lit for the 3.12 kernel, and neutral for the Wheezy kernel. I have installed the 3.12 kernel from wheezy-backports, so that I'm using a recommended kernel.

### btrfs-tools

This package is not available in wheezy-backports:

```
$ apt-cache policy btrfs-tools
btrfs-tools:
  Installed: 0.19+20120328-7.1
  Candidate: 0.19+20120328-7.1
```

The wiki is neutral about the 0.19 2012 version of this package, i.e. it's not in the recommended green highlight, but neither is it in the red danger zone. So it would seem I might need a later version?

### Question

Is it safe to run btrfs from the backports kernel with the current version of tools?

Comment: btrfs-tools has been backported for wheezy now.